# One Server Multiple Client C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, tcp, udp

I know there are a lot of Topics about this issue, but I need a more detailed suggestion about my situation.

My architecture is made up of multiple I/O Peripherals (CLIENT) and a Central Unit(SERVER), connected by Ethernet in a LAN without internet connection.

Clients has to send data (byte) to my Server, the amount of bytes that has to be send is around 20 bytes for each peripheral. 
Moreover, my system should work without being interrupted for minutes, hour or days, it doesn't matter.
Data will be sent through the connection every second (more or less).

So, the question is: Should I use TCP or UDP? Which one is better in this scenario?

I read on some guides on internet, that , it's possible to use either "select()" or "fork()".
I have got some basic programs about the multi-client and single-server communication used in a multiuser chat.
The differnce between what my application should do and a multiuser chat is that I should save data in a file on my Server Machine.

Comment: there is no such thing as C/C++

Comment: `fork` and `select` are unrelated system calls, so it doesn't really make sense to say you can use either.

Comment: I know, but I read on a guide two different ways to use a multiclient communication, that's why I asked about that! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar application and I use UDP with acknowledge, it is a server which attends hundreds of peripherals, time clocks. What I mean by acknowledge; every client sends a packet to the server and waits for an acknowledge packet (ACK). If the client does not receive the ACK (in 2-4 seconds) it sends the same data again.

Why UDP: Because it’s much easier to program than TCP. At the server side you only need one open socket which is bound to a Port and listens for incoming packets. Once a packet is received the server sends an ACK packet to the sending IP. The clients should also bind to an UDP port in order to receive the ACK packet. These ports numbers may be the same or could be different. The server port could be 6050 and the client port could be 6060, for example, it’s up to you.

On the other hand, if you go with TCP you need a socket per connected client, and use `select` or `poll` to see which one has pending data. But in this case you do not need ACK since TCP is reliable and connection oriented.

There are two problems you can face with UDP:

1. `The client’s packet is lost`: This is the easiest one, the client never receives the ACK packet and it will send the same packet again.
2. `The server ACK packet is lost`: In this case the client will send the same packet again, one that the server already got, if packet duplication is a problem then you may consider numbering the packets, I mean, in the data the client sends there is a field integer which represents the packet number. With this info the server can discard duplication: IP/Packet Number.

Comment: This answer solves all my doubts about this issue. So this kind of solution is easier to develop than TCP, but I should face with the two lost cases! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Do you really think that your reimplementation of TCP's reliable delivery is going to be as reliable as the built-in version to TCP? Also, you mention that UDP is simpler because you don't need to maintain separate connections, but then you go on to describe how to maintain separate connections in UDP in order to avoid duplicate packets. Why not just use TCP for what it was designed for? You've basically set out to reimplement it in code and probably do a worse job than the original authors.

Answer (score 0):

The real question should be: do you need reliable delivery of messages? If yes, then you should use TCP.

The overhead of TCP is often overstated. As Jeremy mentions in his comment below, you can avoid much of the overhead in "normal" cases. When bad things happen like packet loss, you will have to pay the overhead in both TCP and UDP, so why not get a working version of a reliable protocol for free? **This will be simpler in the long run.** The connection state tracking that ja_mesa describes is again exactly what TCP already does for you. It's called a sequence number. Do yourself a favor and don't reimplement the wheel. Spend your time coding where it matters instead.

Comment: Yes and no, all the data are important for me! I'm thinking that maybe I avoided a point in the question: in terms of speed, with this low amount of data (around 50bytes in total) TCP put more latency than UDP?

Comment: TCP (with the TCP_NODELAY flag set so that Nagle's algorithm is disabled) will give you about the same latency as UDP except in the case where a packet gets dropped.  (in that case, the TCP layer will have to go back and retransmit the dropped packet before any more data can be sent; whereas UDP will merrily continue on with the next packet)  Since you're on a LAN, that shouldn't happen too often, but it can still happen; you have to decide whether in that scenario it's more important for the dropped packet to be redelivered, or more important that the next packet arrive at its usual time.

Comment: OK I think that now it's more clear how to manage the scenario. Thanks ;)